CMIP6 ts versus tos for Pontential Intensity calculation
As per the title, I am interested in computing the potential intensity (PI) and wondering what the difference between surface temperature (ts) over the ocean and sea surface temperature (tos) in CMIP6 is.
I ask this because I want to compute PI over the whole global grid, and the tos data have, for many models, a different grid, and for some, I suspect that regridding would introduce a considerable amount of bias. I want to know if I am introducing a considerable amount of bias by proxying tos by ts.
To be more precise, I am using monthly data.
I searched online for the relationship between the two but to no avail.
Thank you very much

Maybe you will find the definition of the variables here. It seems ts is different from tos in regions of sea ice. I assume tropical cyclones do not occur there ;-)
